# Combinatorics Question - Group of 30 people.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, combinations, conditional-probability

Five people are randomly selected from 30 people, and then it is found that the height of these five people is increasing or decreasing. What is the probability that the height of the first person among these five people is the shortest among the 30 people.

My attempt:

5 people can be chosen in 30C5

29C4 - combination of all except the shortest person.

So the answer = 29C4/30C5

Just want to check to see if this is the correct way to approach this problem?

Comment: This is vague and confusing.  If the heights decrease as you keep selecting your $5$, then the probability that the first is the shortest of all $30$ is, of course, $0$.  And if the heights are increasing, there isn't enough information to solve the problem.

Comment: there is, of course, a shortest person amongst those $5$.  Knowing that this person happens to have been first doesn't convey anything new.  The probability that you happened to have drawn the shortest one is, of course $\frac 5{30}=\frac 16$.  So, that's the answer if your first draw was the shortest of the $5$.

Comment: We have information that the height of 5 selected people is increasing or decreasing. Can we condition our probability on this? Prob (1st is the shortest|increasing order ) - that the height of the first person among these five people is the shortest of the 30 people = (29 choose 4)/ 2*(30 choose 5)=1/3?

Comment: But we have no idea whether it is increasing or decreasing.  If it is decreasing, the answer is $0$.  If increasing, the answer is $\frac 16$.  If you want to guess that the two scenarios are equally likely, then the answer is the average, namely $\frac 1{12}$. But, really, it is a poorly phrased problem.

Comment: I agree with the comment of @lulu, and I suspect that the problem composer intended the answer of $~\dfrac{1}{12}.~$  However, there is a subtle issue that is unclear to me.  Perhaps lulu will be able to resolve it.  The answer of $~\dfrac{1}{12}~$ assumes that you are equally likely to select $5$ people in either ascending or descending order, regardless of whether the shortest person is in the group.  I regard this as unclear, but probably beyond the perspective that the problem composer intends.  For example, it is unknown whether any of the people are the same height.  ...see next comment

Comment: @lulu Assume that two of the people are the same height.  Then, it is impossible for both of these two people to have been selected.  This implies that the chance of the shortest person being among those selected is greater than $(1/6).$  Since no information is given in this area, I speculate that this nuance was unintended by the problem composer.

Comment: @user2661923  I assumed that no two people had the same height (standard assumption when you have a continuous distribution).  As you say, if it is possible that several people are tied for shortest in the population, the problem is hopeless.

Comment: @lulu I was considering that there might be a unique shortest, but that some of the taller people might be the same height.  Anyway, even with this qualification, situation probably hopeless anyway.

Comment: This seems like issue related to conditional probability including permutations, find the probability of chosing shortest of 30 given that chosen 5 are in increasing or decreasing heights .

Answer (score 1):

Given that there **is** a unique shortest person in the group of $30$, the heights of some of the others being the same or not is irrelevant.

Further, you aren't asking for the probability of the shortest person **being** in the group of $5$ chosen, you are asking that the **first person** in the group of $5$ is the shortest of $30$

That probability is simply $\dfrac1{30}$